# How is vector<int> += 1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6; possible?

Tags: c++

I found this weird syntax in the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/adjacent_filtered.html).

```
std::vector<int> input;
input += 1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6; // <--- How is this possible?
```

Comment: The above is trivially implemented through operator overloading. Do you know what operator overloading is? If you do, then what *specifically* is your question about?

Comment: @AndreyT vector doesn't provide that operator by default so I think it's a fair question as I was confused too.

Comment: I think this code might have issues with name lookup for `operator+=`. You'd have to have a `using` declaration earlier to bring that operator into the current namespace (or a parent of it).

Comment: @Neil Kirk: It is a fair question, no argument here. I just wanted to know what it is supposed to be about: 1) the OP is unfamiliar with operator overloading at all, or 2) the OP  knows about it, but just does not see how it can be used to implement the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just the [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) library. It uses `operator+=` and `operator,` overloads to make the assignments of containers easier.

The syntax breakdown could be given by the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) table.

Essentially `input += 1` would return a proxy object that has `operator,` overloaded that would do the sequential insertions roughly equivalent to:

```
auto x = (input += 1); // input.push_back(1);
x,2; // input.push_back(2);
x,3; // input.push_back(3);
```

This was back in C++98 when they didn't have `std::initializer_list` to directly assign the contents of a container, e.g. `std::vector<int> x = { 1, 2, 3 };`.